# Handling MaxUploadSizeExceededException in servlet filter, how to set flash message in redirect?

Tags: spring, spring-security, multipartform-data

When implementing Spring Security and CSRF protection, some new problems arose especially with multipart file uploading. Reading several threads about this issue, I encountered the following solutions for the subsequent problems:

First, the cause of the problems was that uploading a file did not work anymore after enabling CSRF (actually is is enabled by default in Spring SEcurity).
Because when using multipart request the CSRF token is not send, the MultipartFilter must be specfied before the Spring Security filter. 
According to the documentation of Spring Security (http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-multipartfilter) this can be done by implementing the **beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain** method in the SecurityWebApplicationInitializer class:

```
public class SecurityWebApplicationInitializer extends
    AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer {

  @Override
    protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartFilter());
    }

}
```

This did not work immediately but instead threw an exception, and after some research it appeared that the configured **MultipartFilter** is a ServletFilter that resolves multipart requests by looking up a MultipartResolver in the root application context using a default name of "filterMultipartResolver".

So the following declaration had to be modified and moved from the MvcConfig to the AppConfig class:

```
// was moved from MvcConfig in to fix multipart exception 
  //THe bean MUST be has an id of filterMultipartResolver to be picked up by the
  //MultipartFilter configured in the beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain 
  //(see SecurityWebApplicationInitializer)
  @Bean(name="filterMultipartResolver")
    public CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
      CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
      multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(2000000);
      multipartResolver.setMaxInMemorySize(500000);
      return multipartResolver;
  }
```

Now the file uploading did work again as expected but a little later I found out that the MaxUploadSizeExceededException thrown when a file is too big was not handled anymore by the @ExceptionHandler method in my ExceptionHandlingControllerAdvice class, but instead returned in an ugly HTTP 500 status page by Tomcat.

Reason is that because of the MultipartFilter, the exception is thrown before the request has reached the DispatcherServlet so the ControllerAdvice is never called.

And to continue this cascade of problems and workarounds, after reading various post about this issue I implemented a dedicated Filter to catch and handle the exception and put it in the filter chain:

```
public class MultipartExceptionHandler extends OncePerRequestFilter {


private static Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultipartExceptionHandler.class);


  @Override
  protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
        HttpServletResponse res, FilterChain filterChain)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    try {
        filterChain.doFilter(req, res);
    } catch(MaxUploadSizeExceededException me) {
        handle(req, res, me);
    } catch(ServletException se) {
        if (se.getRootCause() instanceof MaxUploadSizeExceededException) {
            handle(req, res, (MaxUploadSizeExceededException) se.getRootCause());
        } else {
            throw se;
        }
    }

  }

  private void handle(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res,
        MaxUploadSizeExceededException me) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    logger.info("MaxUploadSizeExceededException is handled in custom filter");      
    String redirect = UrlUtils.buildFullRequestUrl(req);
    req.getSession().setAttribute(KeyConstants.FLASH_ERROR_KEY, "File is too big!");
    res.sendRedirect(redirect);
  }
}
```

And the MultipartExceptionHandler filter is added to the filter chain by adding it to the insertFilters method:

```
@Override
  protected void beforeSpringSecurityFilterChain(ServletContext servletContext) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    insertFilters(servletContext, new MultipartExceptionHandler(), new MultipartFilter());
  }
```

And now the MaxUploadSizeExceededException is indeed caught by the filter and the redirected page is shown.
The problem, however, is that response.sendRedirect method does not have the functionality to set the error flash message.
In the original @ExceptionHandler method, this was donw in the following way:

```
    RedirectView rv = new RedirectView(redirectUrl);
    FlashMap outputFlashMap = RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(req);
    if (outputFlashMap != null) {
        outputFlashMap.put(KeyConstants.FLASH_ERROR_KEY, "File is too large");
    }
    return rv;
```

But in the new exception handler filter, this does not work. The call to RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(req) returns null.

Therefore I set the flash message manually in the session just before doing the redirect and now it is displayed, but it remains in the session so has to be removed explicitly somewhere after finishing the redirect. This seems bad practice to me but I have not found a better solution yet.
After all a pretty time consuming cascade of issues after starting using SpringSecurity with CSRF protection but I hope there is a better solution for setting the flash message.

Answer (score 0):

The problem of not showing the flash message is probably due to the use of:

```
FlashMap outputFlashMap = RequestContextUtils.getOutputFlashMap(req);
```

According to the documentation, RequestContextUtilsUtility is a class "for easy access to request-specific state which has been set by the DispatcherServlet."
And because we are handling en exception before reaching the DispatcherServlet, the getOutputFlashMap method probably returns null.

When using following code, the flash message is generated!

```
FlashMapManager flashMapManager = new SessionFlashMapManager();
FlashMap fm = new FlashMap();
fm.put(KeyConstants.FLASH_ERROR_KEY, "File is too large");
flashMapManager.saveOutputFlashMap(fm, req, res);
```